# Boolean wrong output

Tags: java, boolean

my code:

```
public class Kuh {

private String name;
private boolean istSatt;

public Kuh(String name, boolean istSatt) {

}

public double gibMilch() {

    if (istSatt == true) {

        System.out.println(10.0);
        return 10.0;

    } else {

        System.out.println(3.0);
        return 3.0;
    }

}

public void grasen() {

    istSatt = true;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Kuh Frida = new Kuh("Frida", true);

    Frida.gibMilch();
    Frida.grasen();
    Frida.gibMilch();

}
```

}

My problem: I set "istSatt" of the object "Frida" to "true" at creation. So when using the method "gibMilch", it should put out "10". Despite that, it puts out "3", like the boolean would be false, even tho I set it to true. It only puts out "10" after using "grasen". 
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are not assigning the constructor parameters to the fields.

```
public Kuh(String name, boolean istSatt) {
    this.name = name;
    this.istSatt = istSatt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your class variable values in your constructor:

```
public Kuh(String name, boolean istSatt) {
    this.name = name;
    this.istSatt = istSatt;
}
```

Here `this` refers to the class you are instantiating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, as you did not seem to assign to anything on the call to Kuh Frida = new Kuh("Frida", true);

i.e.

```
public class Kuh {

private String name;
private boolean istSatt;

public Kuh(String name, boolean istSatt) {
    this.istSatt=istSatt;
    this.name=name;

}

public double gibMilch() {

    if (istSatt) {

        System.out.println(10.0);
        return 10.0;

    } else {

        System.out.println(3.0);
        return 3.0;
    }

}

public void grasen() {

    istSatt = true;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Kuh Frida = new Kuh("Frida", true);

    Frida.gibMilch();
    Frida.grasen();
    Frida.gibMilch();

}

}
```